# User/Javascript formatting

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

This is my current code:

```
setInterval(function (){
// ==UserScript==
// @name          DriversEd Time Saver!
// @namespace     pandather@gmail.com
// @description   Automatically goes to the next slide once the next button is clickable.
// @copyright     2014+, Marque Kuem
// @license       GPL version 3 or any later version; http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
// @license       (CC); http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
// @version       0.1
// @icon          https://driversed.com/img/logo.png

// @homepageURL   https://duckduckgo.com/
// @supportURL    https://duckduckgo.com/

// @include       https://driversed.com/dashboard/course/*

// ==/UserScript==
    alert('Running!');
    var clickNext = document.querySelectorAll("btn.btn-small.btn_next.btn-advance");
    if(clickNext.length>0){
        alert('Next is clickable.');
    }
},2500);
```

But when I run it it does not work at all, as if the code never runs, how could I fix this? Also, can anyone link me some good guides to getting started with userscripts and javascript?

Comment: You definitely need to move your `setInterval(function() {` line below your metadata block.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't running *at all* -- if you aren't even seeing that first alert, re-arrange your code a bit:

The `==UserScript==` block has to be the first thing.  I *believe* blank lines are allowed, but I don't recall for certain.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          DriversEd Time Saver!
// @namespace     pandather@gmail.com
// @description   Automatically goes to the next slide once the next button is clickable.
// @copyright     2014+, Marque Kuem
// @license       GPL version 3 or any later version; http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
// @license       (CC); http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/
// @version       0.1
// @icon          https://driversed.com/img/logo.png

// @homepageURL   https://duckduckgo.com/
// @supportURL    https://duckduckgo.com/

// @include       https://driversed.com/dashboard/course/*

// ==/UserScript==

setInterval(function (){
    alert('Running!');
    var clickNext = document.querySelectorAll("btn.btn-small.btn_next.btn-advance");
    if(clickNext.length>0){
        alert('Next is clickable.');
    }
},2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

The document needs to be ready, try this :

```
window.onload = function () {
    // your code here
}
```

Or with jQuery :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Greasemonkey user scripts by default run when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires, so using `$(document).ready()` won't do anything. http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at

Answer (score 0):

You havn't shown the HTML source. I guess you want to select buttons with one of the classes `.btn-small`, `.btn_next` or`.btn-advance`. Your query selects an HTML tag "btn" that doesn't exist in any standard. You might want to select: `"button.btn-small, button.btn-next, button.btn-advance"`

Why is there setInterval around the GM script including the metadata block?